# JFace examples in Eclipse like SWT Examples?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

Are there any all-in-one JFace controls example out there like the SWT Examples in Eclipse? Searching (googling and searching here on stackoverflow.com) did not help me.

It would be nice if it was a standalone app or an eclipse plugin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from the [SWT JFace examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CatalogSWT-JFace-Eclipse.htm) and [introduction courses](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/opensource/libraryview.jsp?search_by=gentle+introduction+swt+jface), you have some projects based on JFace controls:

- [JFace Data Binding](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace_Data_Binding)

[image]

- [`CellLabelProvider` TreeViewer example](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2009/06/08/galileo-emf-databinding-%E2%80%93-part-3/)

[image]

- [Nebula project](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/)

> Nebula is a place where different Eclipse-Projects and Independent developers collaborate on building Custom SWT widgets and reuseable UI-Components useable in UI-Applications built using SWT and JFace.

[image]

- [RCP Forms Plugin](http://www.mvmsoft.de/content/plugins/rcpforms/rcpforms.htm#examples)

> [The framework](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/rcpforms/wiki/MainPreconditions) tries to hide some of the complexity of developing forms from you; as with all frameworks there might be points in time where it just does not work and you have to dig deeper into the secrets of SWT, JFace, UI Forms or Databinding

[image]

Comment: I will wait until google indexes this page and vote it up on the search results page :)

Answer (score 4):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFaceSnippets

Answer (score 3):

There is no all-in-one showcase example, but individual samples are available in the Eclipse CVS. You can check out the org.eclipse.jface.snippets project from the Eclipse CVS repo (WebView: http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets)