# How to find jface swt doc?

Tags: java, swt, jface

I use google a lot to find help on JFace/SWT but the only way I find something usefull is when I know the name of the class I want to use. And search again with an other classname related with the first one to finally get to the example of an avanced use of the class (what I wanted for the first time).

Exemple "jface toolbar" doesn't show really interesting results on jface (just some examples on swt). "jface ToolBarManager" show a litle more interesting stuff.

So my question is: where can I find a good advanced documentation on JFace (not only for my toolbar problem) ? A site that list code sample of advance used of JFace components ?

Is this problem of poor documentation due to a framework that is not used a lot ? (execpt in eclipse projet ?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965837/jface-examples-in-eclipse-like-swt-examples) helps? Furthermore: how about the eclipse integration as well as Javadoc locally and integerated in eclipse so F2 brings up the corresponding docs?